# running into android studio issue Could not GET exoplayer

Tags: android, gradle, exoplayer

I have been running into this error while trying to build my app and do not know how to resolve it, when I toggle Gradle offline mode, the error disappears but other dependency requires it to be turned off.

Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/gms/google-services/4.3.4/google-services-4.3.4.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

This is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.6.1'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {

    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my second buid.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'}
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.9'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\Osas Divine\\Desktop\\sckoolite\\unilorin-sckoolboy.jks')
            storePassword '123456/'
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '123456/'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sckoolboy.unilorin"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "d0989000-9ff3-4214-a42b-ed8f5a123456",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 11020
        versionName '5.2.2'
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        archivesBaseName = "Sckoolboy"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation  fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.github.vivchar:ViewPagerIndicator:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.4.1'

    ..........
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'



    // google maps library ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'glide'
    }


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Use google() repo and not bintray

Comment: I have done this and posted my build.gradle file, but i get an error now, on my second buid.gradle  Could not find gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.9.

Comment: Post both build files

Comment: I have done so thanks

Comment: Can you post the new error pls

Comment: Could not find gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.9. I think the one signal dependency needs the exoplayer from the bintray i removed

Comment: Full Error please